# How to show that the integral is finite $\int (1+|x|^{2\delta}) e^{-B|x|^\gamma}dx<\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis

Suppose that $V$ is some continuously differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}^d$ and we have for some $0<\gamma \le 1$ such that for all $|x|\ge C_2$, $V(x)\ge C_1 |x|^\gamma$, for some constants $C_1, C_2>0$.

Given that $|V(x)|\le K(1+|x|^2)$ for some constant $K$, I would like to show that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |V(x)|^\delta e^{-V(x)}dx<\infty, \; \delta = \max(8,\frac{4}{\gamma}).$$

For this it would suffice to show that $$\int |V(x)|^\delta e^{-V(x)}dx \le A\int (1+|x|^{2\delta}) e^{-B|x|^\gamma}dx<\infty$$ for some constants $A,B>0$.
But how can I ensure that $\int (1+|x|^{2\delta}) e^{-B|x|^\gamma}dx<\infty$?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* For any $N$ and any $x\ge 0$, $e^x \ge 1+x^N/N!$. By choosing $N$ appropriately large depending on the parameters in the problem, such as $\delta$ and $\gamma$, it should be straightforward to produce an appropriate bound on the integrand to ensure convergence.

Answer (score 1):

Using hyperspherical coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^d$, you can rewrite your integral as
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\mathrm{d}^dx\,(1+\lVert \vec{x}\rVert^{2\delta}) e^{-B\lVert \vec{x}\rVert^\gamma}=\int\mathrm{d}\Omega_{d-1}\int_0^{\infty}\mathrm{d}r\,r^{d-1}(1+r^{2\delta}) e^{-Br^\gamma},$$
where $\mathrm{d}\Omega_{d-1}$ is the $d$-dimensional solid angle. Calculating this integral is straightforward and yields
$$S_{d-1}\frac{B^{-\frac{d}{\gamma}}\Gamma(\frac{d}{\gamma})+B^{-\frac{d+2\delta}{\gamma}}\Gamma(\frac{d+2\delta}{\gamma})}{\gamma},$$
where $S_{d-1}$ is the surface area of a $d$-dimensional unit sphere. This is finite.